# Gradle buildConfigField Illegal forward reference

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This doesn't work because, in the generated `BuildConfig`, `STORE` ends up being defined before `UNLOCKED` and `PLAYSTORE`. How can I do this differently?

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField 'int', 'UNLOCKED', '0'
        buildConfigField 'int', 'PLAYSTORE', '1'
    }

    productFlavors {
        unlocked {
            buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', 'UNLOCKED'
        }

        playStore {
            buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', 'PLAYSTORE'
        }
    }
}
```

**BuildConfig.java** (generated, playStore flavor)

```
// Fields from product flavor: playStore
public static final int STORE = PLAYSTORE; // ERROR
// Fields from default config.
public static final int PLAYSTORE = 1;
public static final int UNLOCKED = 0;
```

sample use case

```
if(BuildConfig.STORE == BuildConfig.PLAYSTORE)
    validatePurchaseOnPlay();
```

Comment: What's the use-case here? That might help us figure out a workaround.

Comment: @stkent added a use case to the question

Comment: My guess is that the build config fields will always be generated in a 'most specific to least specific' fashion, to allow more specific configuration closures to override fields defined in less specific configuration closures. Running the obvious test supports this idea. Given this, I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you're looking to do using build config fields alone. Your suggested solution seems ok to me; you can presumably locate the constants in any class, not just the custom application subclass?

Comment: @stkent Yes, but I like having the constants defined and used in the gradle script if possible. I guess it's a matter of loose coupling.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your STORE build config field declaration to:

`buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', 'BuildConfig.UNLOCKED'`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define the constants in my `Application` class and then use

```
buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', 'MyApp.UNLOCKED'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve consistency between values using the below approach:

```
android {

    def storeUnlocked = '0'
    def storePlaystore = '1'

    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField 'int', 'UNLOCKED', storeUnlocked
        buildConfigField 'int', 'PLAYSTORE', storePlaystore
    }

    productFlavors {
        unlocked {
            buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', storeUnlocked
        }

        playStore {
            buildConfigField 'int', 'STORE', storePlaystore
        }
    }
}
```

Generated BuildConfig and values will be consistent, if stateUnlocked or statePlaystore changes.

The only missing part is that BuildConfig source code won't show the relation, but that doesn't matter much if you name your fields properly:

```
STORE
STORE_UNLOCKED
STORE_PLAYSTORE
```